# What is the cheapest way to make your own token at the moment?

Tags: tokens

What is the cheapest way to make your own token at the moment?

ERC-20

I want to create a token as cheaply as possible. Someone made a blog post where it cost 30 USD to launch the token but I'm looking for a cheaper way to do it. Raiden? Any other way?

Vesa

Comment: If you want a cheap ERC20 token I'd use UET token https://etherscan.io/address/0x27f706edde3aD952EF647Dd67E24e38CD0803DD6#code.

Comment: These are the warnings from that link:  Warning: The compiled contract might be susceptible to DelegateCallReturnValue (low-severity), ECRecoverMalformedInput (medium-severity), SkipEmptyStringLiteral (low-severity) Solidity compiler bugs.

Comment: The warnings are for the compiler they used, if you use solidity compiler v0.4.15 they will not show up. With every new compiler released etherscan display the potential bugs in contracts compiled with the older versions. But do not take my word before deploying you have to make a security review. For example UET has a workaround for the short address attack, but OpenZeppelin has removed their because it causes other problems, so I'd remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

At this very moment, it would take a gas price of about **80 gwei** to cost **$30** for a standard [**ERC-20 token.**](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard)

I would suggest you lower that to about **21 gwei,** which is about average for a quick confirmation, costing you about **$8.**

Based on data from **http://ethgasstation.info/,** you can go as low as **2 gwei** and still get a confirmation *(could take several hours)* and pay only about **$0.75.**